# ModRewrite - how to build the rules for many things at once?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not even sure if it's possible:

For example, I have a website "hello.com". I want it to:

- if the URL starts with a number, followed by slash and then anything else - it should load from `ids` folder, for example: `hello.com/23/ti8tf38` should silently load `hello.com/ids/?23/ti8tf38`, but the URL should stay the same
- however, if it starts with "not a number", followed by anything else - it should be left it as it is, for example `hello.com/admin/lalala` - should stay the same
- and on top of that, if someone loaded it via `http` - it should redirect the URL to `https`

Is it possible or am I dreaming? Thank you!

Comment: if you are using htaccess then please do share your tried rules in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I did it!

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ ?$1/$2
```

Ok, let me explain, what is going on here:

- `^` means "start looking from the beginning of the string
- `([0-9]+)` - this will match all numbers (one or more) and put it to $1
- `/([^/.]+)$` - means "slash, then any more than one of any character" and put it to $2

After that I create the desired result:
`?$1/$2` - meaning, I want that number, followed by slash and all other characters, so now "234/hahaha" becomes "?234/hahaha"

And if the part before slash is not a number - Apache will continue processing the path as usual.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29298011)

Comment: @TomTaylor: What makes you believe this isn't an answer? They _are_ the author, and they are answering their own question. It would be more valuable with further explanation, but it certainly looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @JeremyCaney : Requesting clarification from the author on how the solution works. For other SO members when they come across this post, it would be helpful when the author has explained how this solution has solved the problem instead of a one liner which does the magic.

Comment: @TomTaylor: You misunderstand the purpose of the _LQP_ queue. Posts that offer an answer should _not_ be deleted. If they are wrong, you should consider _downvoting_ them. If they lack sufficient explanation, you should make a _comment_ encouraging more. But they shouldn’t be _deleted_. ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).